# word for someone who leaves one society for another

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that doesn't have such negative connotations as defector, dissident etc, but still implies actively turning from one set of ideas in favour of another.

Comment: I have a feeling that any such word will have negative connotations: apostate, self-exile, rogue. Your question is somewhat abstract: would 'immigrant' work?

Answer (score 4):

[*Convert*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convert) might work (as a noun); it can be used to denote somebody who has converted:

> 1 a : to bring over from one belief, view, or party to another
> // They tried to *convert* us to their way of thinking.
>
> 1 : to undergo conversion
> // He *converted* to Islam.

<sub>(source: Merriam-Webster)</sub>